# css to stretch full screen static background, works OK everywhere except android chrome?

Tags: android, html, css, google-chrome, background-image

The easiest and most compatible way I know to stretch a static background image and cover the entire screen is:

```css
html { min-height: 100%; }

body 
{
 background: url('https://i.imgur.com/YSRXO72.jpg') no-repeat center fixed;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

The `html { min-height: 100%; }` is just in case there is only little content in the html body, this makes sure the background is still stretched over the entire screen.

This works perfectly fine in almost any situation, however if there is *more* content in the page than fits on the screen, Chrome on Android seems to stretch the background image to cover the entire **page** rather than the screen.

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/7cnuytk2/

(note that I also put the `-webkit` `-moz` and `-o` background size settings there for compatibility, but it also works without)

I deliberately took a test background image here with N/E/S/W markers, you should always see 'center' in the center and either the top+bottom or left+right edges.

The background is properly stretched in all cases, except Chrome on Android which stretches it too much. If there is less content in the html part, e.g. just one `<h1>test</h1>` or something, it works fine on Chrome as well.

Any ideas? Is this a bug in Chrome? Can I work around this without falling back to all sorts of dirty javascript hackery?

Comment: have you tried using 100vh instead of 100% ? This will use 100% of view port height, instead of 100% of it's height. I'm not sure if this will work for all browsers though.

Comment: @JordiFlores thanks for the suggestion, tried that as well, but no difference. Actually, it's just the **min-height** I'm setting, in case the page height is less than the screen (viewport) height, but the problem occurs when the page is taller than the screen. By the way in the jsfiddle example above I'm not setting the html min-height at all, problem occurs there as well.